# Error exporting a const d3.map

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I try to export a `d3.map` dictionary using webpack:

```
import {map, select} from 'd3';

const positionSelect = position => {
  select(position).node().getBoundingClientRect();
};


const dictionary = map();
dictionary.set('Pitcher', positionSelect('#pitcher'))
  .set('Catcher', positionSelect('#catcher'))
  .set('First Base', positionSelect('#firstbase'))
  .set('Second Base', positionSelect('#secondbase'))
  .set('Shortstop', positionSelect('#shortstop'))
  .set('Third Base', positionSelect('#thirdbase'))
  .set('Left Field', positionSelect('#leftfield'))
  .set('Center Field', positionSelect('#centerfield'))
  .set('Right Field', positionSelect('#rightfield'));

export dictionary;
```

I get this error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected { (19:7)

17 |   .set('Right Field', positionSelect('#rightfield'));
18 | 
19 | export dictionary;
   |        ^
20 |
```

Is there a syntax problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) of your `export` statement is not correct; you can read the error message literally. If you want to export a constant that has been declared earlier with a named export, you have to enclose it in curly brackets:

```
export { dictionary };
```

You can, however, do the export while declaring the constant. In that case no curly bracket must be used:

```
export const dictionary = map();
```